# Making React.js aware of vanilla JavaScript DOM updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fiber

Let's assume I have this hierarchy of components in React 16 application:

component **A** is composed of components **B** and **C**

Those components are represented by block HTML elements with some non-zero height.

in `componentDidMount` of component **B** I use vanilla JavaScript in order to find out height of collapsed element. This makes the underlying DOM mutate.

in `componentDidMount` method of component **C** I also use vanilla JS to know offset from the top of the components **B** and **C**.

I know that the offset of those 2 components can't be the same, but in my initial version of code it was the same. After wrapping offset calculating function in `setTimeout` I get good measurements.

```
setTimeout(() => {this.calculateElementsOffset()}, 100)
```

**Is there a way to wire finishing of permutations in component B so I wouldn't use `setTimout` call in component C with magical `100` ms?**

Comment: May be `window.onresize = function(event) { this.calculateElementsOffset() }` ?

Comment: Why does react need to calculate the offset, wouldn't css allow for better positioning?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like component C needs to be aware of component B state. Rather than update the DOM with vanilla JS use react to do so. Calculate the needed height for component B in componentDidMount then save that value to state. Use this new state value in a style attribute to give height to the elements that need it and pass this value as a prop into component C. By using setState to store the value you can be sure your components will update.